# How can I get the # of rows affected by a statement using ADO with JavaScript?

Tags: sql-server, ado

I'm using [ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675532(VS.85).aspx) in a JScript (Microsoft JavaScript dialect) Windows Scripting Host script to update a SQL Server table. I'd like to get the number of rows affected by the update in the script, but JavaScript doesn't have pass-by-reference and so I can't do the usual thing where I receive the records affected from the [`Command#Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681559(VS.85).aspx) function's *RecordsAffected* argument. So I'm looking for the best way to get that info.

For reasons not related directly to this query, I want to avoid using a stored procedure for this although I realize that that *would* work (I'd just return `@@rowcount` out of the SP). I'm trying to find a reliable but simple non-SP means of doing it.

I looked around and found this syntax for the statement:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = (blah blah blah)
WHERE (blah blah blah) ;
SELECT @@rowcount as 'RowsAffected'
```

...which sends me back a one-row `ResultSet` containing the count. That does seem to work, and in my limited testing seems to work correctly (I don't get the wrong count when other operations are also happening, etc.), but it seems...kludgy for some reason.

Is that the best way to do it, given the perhaps-unreasonable constraints I've listed? Cross-platform solutions are not required (welcome, though, as always), it can be Microsoft SQL Server-specific (2005+).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why you think it's kludgy.  Nothing wrong with this approach

Comment: @Andomar: Thanks. Yeah, I can't put my finger on why either, and this "feeling" has been wrong before (as well as right). Sounds like I should probably just go with it. (You might want to turn your comment into an answer; it does directly address my question.)

Comment: Sure, eh, it's not a very informative answer tho ;)

Comment: @Andomar: :-) It's useful, though. I've asked this kind of "Is this a dumb way to do this?" question in other forums and sometimes had a resounding "YES!" back, with examples of the better way. But when the answer is "No, that's fine," there's not a lot more to say. Doesn't make it less useful, though. :-)

Comment: I'm always curious about the back story behind statements like "I want to avoid using a stored procedure"... what could possibly make it better to have ad hoc SQL statements mucking about in application code?

Comment: @Aaron: :-) Yeah, that was begging for comment. It's not an application, and it's not appropriate (in this specific case) to modify the DB to support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you think it's kludgy. Nothing wrong with this approach.