# Get affected count of rows from ADODB & ASP with JScript

Tags: asp-classic, adodb, jscript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the # of rows affected by a statement using ADO with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216630/how-can-i-get-the-of-rows-affected-by-a-statement-using-ado-with-javascript)

We're using MS-SQL7.0, ASP(with Jscript)
there isn't any problem in querying and executing.
But we faced an problem getting affected record count.
We refer to this source

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195048

Here is our source code

```
    var query = "...";
    this.db = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
    this.db.Open(this.connectionString);
    this.db.Execute(query, this.rowCount);
    Response.Write(this.rowCount);

    or

    var query = "...";
    this.db = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
    this.cmd  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command");
    this.cmd.ActiveConnection = this.db;
    this.cmd.CommandText = query;
    this.cmd.Execute(this.rowCount);
    Response.Write(this.rowCount);
```

But this code don't work, `rowCount` are set to its initial value(0).
I think it because primitive type in javascript is always called by value.

Comment: You're right; JScript can't pass parameters by reference.  See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216630/how-can-i-get-the-of-rows-affected-by-a-statement-using-ado-with-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've tried two methods in such a case (I agree, a little bit scratchy.).

**1. Mixing languages**

```
<%@Language=JScript%>
<%
// 
// ..
this.query = "..."; // required
this.rowCount = 0; // required

ExecCommand(this);

//..
this.db.Close();
//..
%>
<script language="vbscript" runat="server">
Sub ExecCommand(obj)
    Dim intAffectedRows
    obj.db.Execute obj.query, intAffectedRows
    obj.rowCount = intAffectedRows 'assign rowCount
End Sub
</script>
```

**2. RDBMS features can be useful.** (you did this)

```
<%@Language=JScript%>
<%
// 
// ..
var query = "...";
//..
this.db.Execute(query);
this.rowCount = this.db.Execute("Select @@ROWCOUNT").Fields.Item(0).Value;
//..
this.db.Close();
//..
%>
```

Comment: I was skeptical about mixing languages, but it works surprisingly well. The function I ended up using is slightly different, but essentially the same:

<script language="vbscript" runat="server">
Function ExecuteQuery(connect, query)
 Dim affectedRows
 connect.Execute query, affectedRows, 129 // 129 = adCmdText|adExecuteNoRecords
 ExecuteQuery = affectedRows
End Function
</script>

Answer (score -1):

The Execute method of the ActiveX Data Objects (ADO) Command object passes by reference an integer value that you can use to retrieve the number of records affected by a SQL UPDATE command.

```
#DEFINE adModeReadWrite 3
#DEFINE adCmdText 1

oConnection = CREATEOBJECT("ADODB.Connection")
oCommand = CREATEOBJECT("ADODB.Command")

lcConnString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};" + ;
   "SERVER=YourServerName;" + ;
   "DATABASE=pubs"

lcUID = "YourUserID"
lcPWD = "YourPassword"

oConnection.ATTRIBUTES = adModeReadWrite
oConnection.OPEN(lcConnString, lcUID, lcPWD )

* Use the command object to perform an UPDATE
* and return the count of affected records.
strSQL = "UPDATE roysched SET royalty = royalty * 1.5"
liRecordsAffected = 0
WITH oCommand
   .CommandType = adCmdText
   .ActiveConnection = oConnection
   .CommandText = strSQL
   .Execute(@liRecordsAffected)
ENDWITH
=MESSAGEBOX("Records affected: " + LTRIM(STR(liRecordsAffected)))

* Set the royalty column back to its previous value.
strSQL = "UPDATE roysched SET royalty = royalty / 1.5"
liRecordsAffected = 0
WITH oCommand
   .CommandType = adCmdText
   .ActiveConnection = oConnection
   .CommandText = strSQL
   .Execute(@liRecordsAffected)
ENDWITH


=MESSAGEBOX("Records affected: " + LTRIM(STR(liRecordsAffected)))
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195048

Comment: Thanks to Mr Zee Tee, but We don't want to get data or retrieved record count of query. We want to get the count of excuted data(eg:insert, update, delete query). I wish you notice me, if You knew it too. :)

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to get the # of affected rows like that, but then again i'm not too familiar with JScript.

Comment: OK. Thanks anyway Mr. Zee Tee :-)

Comment: Try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195048

Comment: Thanks. Mr. Zee Tee :) .But that's exactly I founded and applied to our JScript Source. described in main article. the variable liRecordsAffected must be called by refrenece. But in javascript, there's no way to call primitive type by referrence, I think.

Comment: I solved this problem. But I avoid main issue. I send a query(select @@rowcount) as soon as executing insert, update, delete query.

Comment: The referenced link is broken, and this doesn't look like JScript, but rather some VBScript in SQL all-caps style. It certainly doesn't address the main issue, which is that JScript doesn't appear to support passing variables by reference,